# Can an animal like dog or cat "row" with its paws on the ground when playing or doing smth else?

Tags: verbs

Or what is the name of the movement of the cat or dog's paws after they went to the toilet on the ground? Or, for example, when a dog is burying a bone, **are they rowing** (on the lawn or ground)? Thanks.

Comment: As explained below the usual word is "paw" ... the phrase "paw the ground" describes what you mean.  (It's worth noting though that "row the ground" would work perfectly as a clever literary description of a (say) cat which is playfully, well, rowing the ground - it is a lovely phrase.  Again to repeat it is NOT standard, it would be your invention in prose writing.}

Answer (score 11):

The animal is said to **paw the ground** when it scrapes it with its paws (or with its hooves, as the case may be).

See **paw**, verb.

When a dog is digging a hole to bury a bone, the animal is said to **dig**.  There's no special verb that means "to dig a hole with the paws".

An animal that digs a tunnel is said to **burrow**.

Comment: The connotations behind the verb _paw_ are soft. ie an animal paws you when it softly rubs its paw against you.

Comment: @Jamie Clinton:The meaning of the verb **paw** actually implies just the opposite of a soft and gentle touch.

Comment: Pawing is when a dog slaps (brushes?) your leg to get your attention, not when they are furiously digging. If a cat slaps your outstretched hand, that is pawing. When a cat swipes at a mouse with its claws, it is not pawing the mouse.

Comment: @Tuoshuo A lion pawing you might knock you back a bit, but you likely wouldn't fall down. A lion maiming you is not pawing you.

Comment: @Jamie Clinton: Just look this verb up in a few good dictionaries. The discussion here is about the verb, not *canis familiaris*.

Comment: I know the dictionary definition (it's in the word...an animal hits something with their paw). No force is implied. If an animal swings their paw at you with force, they are not pawing you. Mauling, maiming, clawing maybe, but not pawing. _to paw_ can also be used to discuss human interactions and again, there is no force implied. Exactly the opposite in fact.

Comment: I'll alter my definition to end this discussion: pawing needs not be soft, but if it is forceful, it is not pawing.

Comment: *Pawing* is correct here. When a dog is trying furiously to get out of a locked room, we say it is "pawing" the door. Animals also "paw the ground" when they're agitated (like a bull getting ready to charge, or a horse that wants to move but is held in check). In fact, "pawing the ground" is almost a set phrase for this kind of movement.

Comment: @JamieClinton: You're trying to distill a meaning based on what you think of whan you think of a paw. [The dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/paw) specifically describes it as "to scrape", "to beat", "flail wildly", "to strike" and "to search especially carelessly or roughly". Pawing is in no way inherently soft. It _can_ be soft, but it can be hard as well.

Answer (score 7):

No, not **rowing**. You can describe their actions as **scratching, scraping, scuffing or clawing**, depending on the context, although one often speaks of dogs **covering their excrement with dirt** or **kicking dirt over their excrement**.

https://pets.thenest.com/dogs-scratch-ground-after-defecating-3549.html
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Claw
https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/scratch

Comment: scuffing is the verb I'd have suggested. But as the link says, they are not actually covering their poop, but adding individual scent markings

Comment: Sounds like the dog is digging a hole to me.

Answer (score 1):

The closest English word for the Slavic рити/рыть should be "dig" and for заривати/зарывать it's "bury".

So a dog may choose to *[dig up](https://pets.webmd.com/dogs/guide/why-dogs-dig-what-you-can-do#1)* a bone it *buried* yesterday if it feels hungry. And likewise, both dogs and cats will frequently *bury* their poop to [show their submissiveness](https://www.livescience.com/33147-why-do-cats-bury-their-poop.html).

*Rowing*(гребти/грести) describes the act of propelling a boat with a paddle and cannot be applied to solid substances.

Comment: With regard to your last sentence,"row" could be applied figuratively to solid substances if somebody was moving across such a surface in a way that looked like rowing a boat. But I agree that the literal meaning requires being on water.